# Flowplayer: disable centered play button per clip in playlist

Tags: flowplayer

I want to disable the centered play button on the video screen per clip in my playlist.

Globally the button can be disabled with the play attribute:

```
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer.swf", {
  // stuff
  play: null, // or play: {opacity: 0}
  // more stuff
});
```

Because I can't access the flowplayer configuration, but the playlist I need this for the entries there.

Is this also possible in some way via playlist for specific entries?